# How to show ForeignKey value even if object deleted?

Tags: python, django

I have simple link below and it links to model object `actor` with `id` that is deleted (one table references to other). This rises an error, but I want to get that `id` to create link anyway. How to do that?

```
<a href="{% url "actor:view" notification.actor.id %}">
```

error:

```
Reverse for 'view' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['actor/view/(?P<id>\\d+)$']
```

Comment: if  ForeignKey is deleted and value is empty: what really do you want?

Comment: Value is not empty (in `postgres` database). Deleted object in other table.

Comment: please, show more html and view

Comment: Thank you for reply. The question is how to print `{{ notification.actor.id }}` if `id` value is in database table, but that referenced model is deleted. Currently `{{ notification.actor.id }}` in template is empty.

Comment: did you try `default_if_none` ?

Comment: I don't need default, I need to show real id number. But when I try to print, it has None then showing integer id

Answer (score 0):

It is not good way, but i hope it help you.

```
<a href="{% url "actor:view" notification.actor.id|default_if_none:1 %}">
                                              <!-- ^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the regex in your url pattern, try it this way : ['actor/view/(?P\d+)/$']